Gauss, Cantor, and infinite confusion
There is an interesting comment by Gauss on "infinite magnitude as a
complete thing" that has invited varying interpretations.  In a
well-known passage, Gauss criticized the use of infinity in
mathematics in the following terms:

"I protest first of all against the use of an infinite quantity as a
completed one, which is never permissible in mathematics. The
infinite is only a façon de parler, where one is really speaking of
limits to which certain ratios come as close as one likes while
others are allowed to grow without restriction."

This has often been interpreted by historians such as Dauben as
rejection of "completed" infinity, also known as actual infinity (and
contrasted with potential infinity).  Actual infinity is considered to
have been "tamed" by Cantor, who based his theory of infinite ordinals
and cardinals on the idea of actual infinity.  Hilbert famously
referred to such a framework as a "Cantorian paradise".
However, other historians give a different interpretation of Gauss'
passage.  Waterhouse points out in

WILLIAM C. WATERHOUSE, GAUSS ON INFINITY, Historia Mathematica 6
(1979), 430-436

that the context of Gauss's passage is a criticism of a contemporary
mathematician's (Schumacher) attempted proof of the parallel
postulate, using the idea of a circle of a radius of infinite
magnitude.  Accordingly, it is not infinite cardinals but rather
infinite magnitudes that are rejected by Gauss.  Such infinite
magnitudes were formalized in nonstandard analysis, and can be called
infinite ringinals (because they are elements of a ring such as the
ring of integers), to contrast them with Cantorian infinities.
Meanwhile, user Conifold (who seems to be a professional historian)
argues
vigorously
that Waterhouse's argument is inconclusive, and Dauben (and many other
historians) may well be right.
This leads us to the following questions:

1. Did Gauss criticize infinite cardinals or infinite ringinals?


2. Are there any texts by Gauss that could shed light on his attitude toward what Leibniz termed "infinite wholes" (as opposed to infinite magnitudes)?

Moore notes the following:

"Waterhouse [1979] has noted in this journal, correctly, that Gauss’s
remarks were not directed against set theory, which in any case did
not exist at that time. But Cantor saw Gauss’s remarks as aimed
against the actual infinite, etc."

See Moore, Gregory H.$\;$ Hilbert on the infinite: the role of set
theory in the evolution of Hilbert's thought.  Historia Math. 29
(2002), no. 1, 40–64.
In more detail, Lipschitz understood Cantor as interpreting the
Gaussian passage as opposition to actual infinity (i.e., completed
infinite collections).  Waterhouse argues that Lipschitz's comment is
the source of the commonly found opinion that Gauss opposed actual
infinity (as opposed to potential infinity; both of these are
Aristotelian notions).  The question is whether in the quoted passage,
Gauss opposed (A) actual infinite collections or (B) infinite
magnitudes.  In modern mathematics, these are formalized respectively
by (A) cardinals and (B) nonstandard numbers (which can be referred to
as "infinite ringinals" because they are elements of a ring).
It should be noted that the existence of infinite cardinals is,
mathematically speaking, "transverse" to the existence of "infinite
ringinals"; see e.g., Enayat's
answer.  Historically,
Leibniz used infinite magnitudes (that he referred to as infinita
terminata) but rejected completed infinities that he referred to as
"infinite wholes", already in the 17th century.  In the 18th century,
Euler made routine use of infinite quantities.
While there is no evidence that Gauss distinguished between the
notions of "infinite magnitudes" and "infinite sets" in his letter to
Schumacher, it is legitimate to ask what notion of infinity Gauss was
referring to in this letter, based on the context of the
Gauss-Schumacher discussion.
I posed the question at the philosophy
SE where it did
not generate any answers, and at the history of science
SE where it generated one
answer which seems to lack mathematical expertise to distinguish
between different types of infinity.
Waterhouse's paper on Gauss was reported on here.

If this is a question about this particular passage from Gauss, surely it is simply unclear / underdetermined whether this is a criticism of the idea of completed infinities in general, or whether this is merely a criticism of arguments that involve circles with infinite diameters. If the question is about Gauss' general view, then I am less sure as I'm not familiar enough with what Gauss says elsewhere.

@provocateur, I am not sure it is as "simple" as you present it, because the remark occurred in the context of a certain mathematical discussion.  One may therefore be able to infer from the context what Gauss's thinking was.  Also, it is not out of the question that a text might turn up where Gauss did criticize "infinite cardinals" (of course without using the term), as for example Cauchy does in an obscure text from the 1830s (namely, he insists that only potential infinity is possible, and like Leibniz mentions Galileo's paradox).

@MikhailKatz I don't see how you can expect a definitive answer to this question since it tacitly assumes that Gauss clearly distinguished between two concepts that, as you yourself admit, he did not clearly distinguish between. Voting to close as opinion-based.

@TimothyChow, with illustrious predecessors like Leibniz and Euler who knew how to distinguish between these two notions of infinity, one can venture that there is a good chance that Gauss should have been capable of doing so.  I only wrote that I am not aware of any text where Gauss would have mentioned such a difference.  Also, Cauchy did.  So you can withdraw your friendly vote.

@MikhailKatz If you rephrase your question to ask, is there any text by Gauss in which he makes a clear distinction along the lines that Leibniz and Euler did, then that becomes a factual question, and I will withdraw my vote to close.

@TimothyChow, OK, see question 2 there.

@MikhailKatz I have retracted my close vote.

In Gauss's quote he does not appear to be discussing cardinalities of sets.

As for question 1, the context is a discussion about whether a certain argument for the parallel postulate that involves drawing a circle with an infinite radius is a good argument. I just don't see how in this context we can infer Gauss's views about the nature of infinity in general. As to question 2, I'm interested to see whether people will be able to point to other remarks of Gauss on the nature of infinity.

@pro, thanks, that wasWaterhouse's point: Gauss criticized cavalier use of a radius of infinite magnitude in a geometric context, whereas for a hundred years historians have been misreading Gauss as rejecting completed infinity (as later championed by Cantor), and continue to do so even after Waterhouse's article, claiming that the latter is not definitive.  Is that because it fits the narrative they constructed? ...

... Or  because they refuse to acknowledge Abraham Robinson's role in establishing historical continuity between infinite magnitudes as used by Leibniz and Euler, on the one hand, and nonstandard integers of modern infinitesimal theories, on the other?
